# Problem while working on the Flutter TextEditingController

Tags: flutter, dart

I wrote the code because I wanted to add "-" when I entered the number.

I'm satisfied with the results.

ex) 123-15-64253

However, after - is entered, it cannot be erased even if you try to erase it with a keyboard.

```
late TextEditingController _tfText = TextEditingController(text: '');
 .
 .
 .
late List list1 = [3,5];

return TextFormField(
  onChange: (value) {
    late String item = _tfText.text;
    late String item2;

    list1.forEach((i) {
      
      if( item.length == i ){
        item2 = item + "-";
        _tfText.text = item2;

        text.selectin = TextSelection(
          baseOffset   : item2.length,
          extentOffset : item2.length
        );
      }
    });
  }
)
```

Why is that?

Comment: I use [this package](https://pub.dev/packages/mask_text_input_formatter), you might want to give a try.

Comment: @Peter Koltai.
 Thank you so much.
I solved it thanks to you. Thank you so much.